# Search a particular position in a string in R

Tags: r, string, search, position

I have a character string containing 11 characters. For example, 36001018396, 36130483208, 31368078318

I would like to return all DISTINCT values populating the 11th position. So, for the above:

6,8.

I'm sure the stringR package could accomplish this, but I am running into roadblocks.
Thank you for you help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you are storing all of your character strings, you could use a combination of:

`substring('66001018396',11,11)` and `unique(vector)`

where `substring` takes the character at the 11th position, which you can then save to a vector. You can then determine the unique values in the vector using the unique command. For example:

```
> values = c("6", "2", "2", "6", "3")
> unique(values)
[1] "6" "2" "3"
```